# Best practices for completely unlinking react-native libraries from your application?

Tags: react-native

I have currently just uninstalled a package that was causing some bloat, unnecessarily, in my React Native project.

The `react-native unlink xxx` command did most of the work, but I noticed there were a lot of left over files (font files I noticed at first glance). I then ran a search for the package in my main application and found a ton of references to it in the iOS and Android build folders.

What is the best way to clean up fully after unlinking a package?

1. react-native unlink XXX
2. remove the item from your package.json, uninstall it.
3. manual cleanup (what steps are recommended here)?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you delete `/ios` and `/android` and run `react-native upgrade`. After that you can link whichever package you want.

Comment: that's the 3rd step anyway.

Comment: @milkersarac pods need to be reinstalled i assume, anything else that would be missing in iOS? Android also in android? also then running react-native link I assume to ensure everything is re-linked?

Comment: @EnieJakiro thanks for the great insights!

Comment: @AustinWitherow I said that to **milkersarac** anyway